# Unable to access backbone Model properties from controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, backbone.js

I have faced an error regarding interaction between BackboneJS and spring mvc controller. I am unable to access model properties while adding model to collection list. The error prone part of my JS code is as follows:

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     taskName: '',
     category:'',
     completed: false,
     dateCreated:0,
     dateCompleted:0
   }
 });



var TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Task,
   url : "/todoCollection"
 });

// instance of the Collection
var taskList = new TaskList();


var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({

   tagName: 'div',
   render: function(){


       var itemHTML = _.template($('script.itemview').html());

     this.$el.html(itemHTML(this.model.toJSON()));
     return this; // enable chained calls
   }

});

 var TaskCreateView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el : ".taskcreate",
     initialize : function(){
         this.render();
         this.input = this.$('#taskInput');
         this.categoryInput = this.$('#taskCategory');
         taskList.on('add', this.addAll, this);
         taskList.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
         taskList.fetch();
     },

     render : function(){
         var createListHTML = _.template($('script.create-task-view').html());
         this.$el.append(createListHTML);
         var createListHTML = _.template($('script.list-view').html());
         this.$el.append(createListHTML);
     },

     events: {
         'click button#createButton':'createTask'
     },

     createTask : function(e){

         if(this.input.val() == ''){
            alert("Task name expected");
            return;
         }

         if(this.categoryInput.val() == 'None'){
            alert("Enter valid category");
            return;
          }

         var newTask = {

             taskName: this.input.val().trim(),
             completed: false,
             category: this.categoryInput.val().trim()

         };


         taskList.create(newTask,{ wait: true });
         this.input.val(''); // clean input box
         this.categoryInput.val('None');

     },



     addOne: function(task){
         var view = new TaskView({model: task});
         $('#listDiv').append(view.render().el);
     },

     addAll: function(){
         this.$('#listDiv').html(''); // clean the todo list
         taskList.each(this.addOne, this);
     }


});

var TodoAppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#todoApp',

    initialize : function(){
      this.render();
    },

    render : function(){
        var appHTML = _.template($('script.appview').html());
        this.$el.append(appHTML);
        var taskCreateView = new TaskCreateView();
    }

});

var TodoApp1 = new TodoAppView();
```

The url **/todoCollection** in TaskList is mapped to a spring mvc controller which is defined as follows:

```
package com.glider.controller;


import com.glider.model.Todo;
import com.glider.service.TodoService;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class TodoCollectionController {

    @Autowired
    TodoService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todoCollection",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createTodo(@RequestParam(value = "taskName")String taskName,
                          @RequestParam(value = "category")String category){

        System.out.println("Method working");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            Todo todo =  service.create(taskName,category);
            String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(todo);
            return jsonInString;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "error";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todoCollection",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllTodo(){


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Todo> todoList = service.findAllTasks();
            String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(todoList);
            return jsonInString;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "error";

    }


}
```

The controller method **createTodo** is expecting parameters like **taskName** and **category**. These properties are also mentioned while adding a new **task** to **taskList**. On executing above codes on server I am getting an error from browser console defined as follows:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/todoCollection 400 (Bad Request)
```

On Server side error exists as follows:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'taskName' is not present.
```

I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: you are sending json data to the server.Check how to access json data on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Java class that represents the JSON object spring can map values to. `@RequestParam` is for mapping query string parameters from the request, which is not the case with REST and backbone.

Your code should look something like:

```
public String createTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo)){}
```

and spring will set the values in `todo` from the JSON request